# Explaining paternal haplogroup of J2a1b1 for Chinese person?

Tags: haplogroup, china

I'm from Beijing, China. I recently did a DNA test, to my surprise, my paternal haplogroup is J2a1b1.

Also, the test shows that I have 2.7% Balkan which is quite amazing.

How is that possible?

I belong to one of the ethnic minorities in China (Hui People) and I guess some of my ancestors may come from Central Asia.

Is that Balkan ancestry somehow related to my paternal haplogroup?

Comment: It depends very much on where your Hui-family origins are. Do you have relatives in Xinjiang? It may be a connection between the Göktürk/Turk tribes from northern China and the Turks who temporary inhabited the Balkans. Anyway you'll have to give more information on that. ;))

Answer (score 3):

J2a1b1 has been found among the Uighur population of Xinjiang. This is interesting to me because my Y-DNA is also J2a1b1 and I am Ashkenazi Jewish, with my paternal line coming from northern Lithuania.